# Angular2: I want to have a different html structure for the login page and home page

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application

I have two things I need to get working in my ng2 project

1. I want to have a different HTML structure for the login page and home page (My router-outlet  in app module is surrounded with a template HTML structure .But this base template needs to be different for login and home page
2. I want the same URLs for jobseeker users and employer users .Jobseeker and employers pages are in seperate modules (Therefore i think i need to find a way to set a routing module based on a session . But dont know how to do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want different layouts for different pages, do not put the layout in the app module. Instead, use two router outlets:

   < router-outlet name='layout'> < /router-outlet>

   ```
   < router-outlet name='content'> < /router-outlet>
   ```

Now, load the layout and contents appropriately.

2. If you want to use the same URL for two purpose, you may configure not to change the URL when navigate using skipLocationChange.

   router.navigateByUrl("/employer", { skipLocationChange: true });

Answer (score 0):

1. Have separate components for login and home page and have the structure html in those components. In your app module have a router-outlet in the body tags and nothing else. This will load the two different components.
2. If I understand this correctly, the jobseeker users and employer users can be separate components that are both children of the component with the url you wish to specify. For example, you might have a users component and then within that component you can have another router-outlet that will show which users you want based on a query parameter. This is difficult to explain without having a better understanding of what you want.